# ¿Cómo emular una aplicación Android con Ionic en Linux de 32-bits?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic

Previamente he instalado el [Stand-alone SDK](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools), luego de descargarlo lo he actualizado usando:

```
$ ./android update sdk --no-ui
(Larga espera)
```

Después instalé [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/), inicié mi sesión y creé una aplicación desde [Ionic Creator](https://creator.ionic.io/):

```
$ sudo npm install -g cordova ionic
...
$ ionic login
...
$ ionic start chambba creator:xxxxxxxxxxxx
...
$ cd chambba/
$ ionic platform add android
...
```

Puedo usar `ionic build` sin que me cause problemas:

```
$ ionic build android
...
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 21.078 secs
Built the following apk(s):
    /home/cesar/Development/Work/chambba/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
```

Pero cuando intento usar `ionic emulate` para emular la aplicación:

```
$ ionic emulate android
Running command: /home/cesar/Development/Work/chambba/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /home/cesar/Development/Work/chambba
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: /home/cesar/Development/Work/chambba/platforms/android/cordova/run --emulator
ANDROID_HOME=/home/cesar/Development/Android/android-sdk-linux
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386

/home/cesar/Development/Work/chambba/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                    ^
Error executing "adb devices": /home/cesar/Development/Android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb: 1: /home/cesar/Development/Android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb: Syntax error: ")" unexpected

Error: /home/cesar/Development/Work/chambba/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 1
```

Si ejecuto `adb` independientemente:

```
$ ./adb devices
bash: ./adb: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Según he leído necesito un sistema de 64-bits, sin embargo me encuentro limitado en este aspecto ya que mi Laptop corre bajo el sistema Ubuntu 14.04 de 32-bits.

En estos casos lo que recomiendan es hacer uso del flag `-force-32bit` o exportando la variable al entorno `export ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT=true`, entonces lo que hice fue agregarlo en mi `.profile` junto con otras rutas:

```
$ cat ~/.profile
...
export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/Development/Android/android-sdk-linux"
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Development/Android/android-sdk-linux/platform_tools:$HOME/Development/Android/android-sdk-linux/tools
export ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT=true
$ source ~/.profile
```

Sin embargo, el error mencionado persiste. ¿Existe alguna forma de emular la aplicación en mi sistema de 32-bits?

Comment: quizas esto ayude -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26783594/phonegap-cordova-build-android-node-modules-q-q-js-throw-e#answer-27738942 y tenga que # cordova platform remove android
# cordova platform add android , porque se a quedado corrupto con los cambios que realizo Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel gracias, pero con eso no pude solucionar mi problema

Answer (score 1):

Saludos, me paso lo mismo (también uso una distrito de 32 bit). Revisa tu SDK Manager y ve si tienes la version de android platform-tools 23.1, de ser así te comentó que desde esa versión los binarios para ADB están sólo soportados para arquitecturas 64 bits. Por eso no me corría más el emulador de Android Studio. Tuve q ir a la carpeta del SDK y borrar la carpeta de plataforma tool 23.1 y descargar una versión anterior como la 23.0.1

Te dejó el enlace por si quieres probar.
http://www.april1985.com/android-sdk-offline/

Ojalá te sirva.

Comment: Hola, tu respuesta es prometedora, déjame probarlo.